# Интервал между несколькими датами ClickHouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Есть таблица в ClickHouse, которая постоянно дополняется, формата:

```
date_time           | shop_id | item_id | status | balance
---------------------------------------------------------------
2022-09-09 13:00:01 | abc     | 1234    | 0      | 0
2022-09-09 13:00:00 | abc     | 1234    | 1      | 3
2022-09-09 12:50:00 | abc     | 1234    | 1      | 10
```

В таблице хранятся статусы по каждому item_id, при изменении остатка, добавляется новая запись со статусом, остатком и временем. Если остаток = 0, то статус меняется на 0.

Нужно посчитать какое кол-во времени(сколько минут) был доступен каждый item_id в магазине за день. Статус при этом может меняться несколько раз в день.
Если item_id доступен - статус 1.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это посчитать?

Comment: Посчитать `LEAD(date_time) - date_time` в CTE, в основном запросе оставить записи с единичкой, группировать/суммировать.

Comment: @Akina, в таблицу еще добавили поле balance, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно учитывать еще и его?